# Can't connect to the Internet even though I was able during installation(Debian)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

As I said in the title i have difficulties connecting to the Internet. During installation of Debian 7.1 I provided wizard with htc_9271.fw file when it asked. After that I connected to the ftp server and downloaded some additional files. After installation, my card adapter TP-LINK WN722N turned off and I can't seem to get it working. In the network options it says: wireless is disabled by hardware switch. There is no switch on this card and it be should turned on by default. Also it works perfectly on Windows 7(after using drivers). Before installing Debian i I have tried Ubuntu and it also did not work. I am a newbie so I am not sure if I provided you with enough information. Feel free to ask for more. I greatly appreciate your help since I need to have my UNIX distribution setup for computer science lectures/labs.

Here is some output from terminal:

lspci -knn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX [1039:0671]
    Subsystem: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX [1039:0671]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge [1039:0004]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] [1039:0968] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface [0101]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller [1039:5513] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e7]
    Kernel driver in use: pata_sis
00:03.0 USB controller [0c03]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller [1039:7001] (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e7]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:03.1 USB controller [0c03]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller [1039:7001] (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e7]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:03.3 USB controller [0c03]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller [1039:7002]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e7]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [1039:0191] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1815]
    Kernel driver in use: sis190
00:05.0 IDE interface [0101]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode [1039:1183] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e7]
    Kernel driver in use: sata_sis
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge [1039:000a]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge [1039:000a]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:0f.0 Audio device [0403]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller [1039:7502]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1783]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 [Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series] [1002:95c4]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:19e2]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE771 802.11bgn Wireless Mini PCIe Card [AR9281] [1a3b:1067]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:a111 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0116 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   52184  3 
parport_pc             22036  0 
ppdev                  12651  0 
lp                     12797  0 
parport                31254  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
bnep                   17288  2 
rfcomm                 28626  0 
bluetooth             103791  10 rfcomm,bnep
binfmt_misc            12813  1 
uinput                 12991  1 
nfsd                  173890  2 
nfs                   265921  0 
nfs_acl                12463  2 nfs,nfsd
auth_rpcgss            32143  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                31978  1 nfs
lockd                  57277  2 nfs,nfsd
sunrpc                143904  6 lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl,nfs,nfsd
loop                   17810  0 
uvcvideo               56896  0 
videodev               61658  1 uvcvideo
media                  13692  2 videodev,uvcvideo
arc4                   12418  4 
ath9k                  67806  0 
radeon                636657  0 
ath9k_htc              43078  0 
ath9k_common           12648  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k
ath9k_hw              311433  3 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k
joydev                 17010  0 
ath                    17114  4 ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k
mac80211              171389  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k
ttm                    47786  1 radeon
cfg80211              113445  4 mac80211,ath,ath9k_htc,ath9k
snd_hda_codec_si3054    12662  1 
drm_kms_helper         22738  1 radeon
snd_hda_codec_realtek   142274  1 
drm                   146387  3 drm_kms_helper,ttm,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           12713  1 radeon
i2c_core               19116  5 i2c_algo_bit,drm,drm_kms_helper,radeon,videodev
asus_laptop            18060  0 
acpi_cpufreq           12807  0 
mperf                  12421  1 acpi_cpufreq
coretemp               12770  0 
snd_hda_intel          21786  2 
snd_hda_codec          63477  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054
snd_hwdep              12943  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                53461  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_si3054
snd_page_alloc         12867  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
battery                12986  0 
snd_seq                39512  0 
snd_seq_device         13016  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              22356  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
psmouse                59609  0 
snd                    42722  13 snd_timer,snd_seq_device,snd_seq,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054
sparse_keymap          12680  1 asus_laptop
rfkill                 18516  5 asus_laptop,cfg80211,bluetooth
ac                     12552  0 
power_supply           13283  3 ac,battery,radeon
processor              27565  3 acpi_cpufreq
evdev                  17225  18 
input_polldev          12802  1 asus_laptop
video                  17459  0 
soundcore              12921  1 snd
pcspkr                 12515  0 
serio_raw              12803  0 
button                 12817  0 
ext4                  306996  1 
crc16                  12327  2 ext4,bluetooth
jbd2                   52330  1 ext4
mbcache                12938  1 ext4
usb_storage            35142  0 
sd_mod                 35425  3 
crc_t10dif             12332  1 sd_mod
sg                     21476  0 
sr_mod                 17468  0 
cdrom                  34813  1 sr_mod
ata_generic            12439  0 
sata_sis               12482  2 
ohci_hcd               22059  0 
thermal                13103  0 
thermal_sys            17752  3 thermal,video,processor
pata_sis               13123  1 sata_sis
ehci_hcd               35509  0 
libata                125014  3 pata_sis,sata_sis,ata_generic
usbcore               104555  6 ehci_hcd,ohci_hcd,usb_storage,ath9k_htc,uvcvideo
scsi_mod              135037  5 libata,sr_mod,sg,sd_mod,usb_storage
sis190                 18004  0 
mii                    12595  1 sis190
usb_common             12338  1 usbcore
```

dmesg | grep firmware

```
[    6.777252] usb 1-1: firmware: agent loaded htc_9271.fw into memory
[    6.782644] [drm:radeon_pci_probe] *ERROR* radeon kernel modesetting for R600 or later requires firmware-linux-nonfree.
```

uname -r

```
3.2.0-4-686-pae
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:54:84:48:f2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xdead 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1536 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1536 (1.5 KiB)
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```